# Docker volume NFS uid

Tags: docker, nfs, docker-volume, dovecot

I'm in the process of setting up `dovecot` as docker container. I want to store the `Maildir` via NFS on a NAS.

I'm creating the docker volume like this:

```
docker volume create \
  --driver local \
  --opt type=nfs \
  --opt o=addr=<ip>,rw \
  --opt device=:/vmail \
  vmail
```

in the `Dockerfile`, I have:

```
RUN useradd -m -p vmail -s /bin/false vmail
VOLUME /home/vmail
```

and to run the docker container, I call:

```
docker run \
  -dit \
  -p 993:993 \
  --mount source=vmail,target=/home/vmail \
  my_dovecot
```

but as a result I get:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: chown /var/lib/docker/volumes/vmail/_data: operation not permitted.
```

The issue is clearly related to the way I mount the NFS volume, as - if I drop the `--mount` statement - it works ok (but obviously can't access my `Maildir` data from the NAS).
I'm pretty sure that this is related to the fact that `dovecot` is trying to access the `Maildir` as `vmail` user, and that user doesn't have permissions on the NFS share - but even giving everybody write access on the NFS share doesn't make a difference.

I'm looking for any advice to get this NFS volume properly mounted into my docker container.

Regards
  StHeine

Comment: You can try running the container as root user `docker run --user root ...` to see if it is a user error on permissions.

Comment: Knowing what the Dockerfile for your `my_dovecot` container looks like would help.

Answer (score 0):

in the meantime I found the issue.
to fix this, I had to remove the `-m` in the `useradd` command to prevent it from creating the `/home/vmail` directory:

```
RUN useradd -p vmail -s /bin/false vmail
VOLUME /home/vmail
```

because if that exists, mounting the volume into that same place, docker tries to copy existing folder data into the volume and `chown` this to the volume's ownership. due to the fact that the volume comes via NFS from a NAS is doesn't have proper uids, but `nobody` - and `chown` fails.

I found references to `nocopy` to prevent docker from doing this, but I haven't figured how to set that in the `docker create` statement.